# Croatian encoding for BytesIO Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, encoding, character-encoding

So I made a Python program that will add text to a PDF template but I have a problem with showing chars like č,ć,š,ž,đ etc.

That text is firstly put on canvas:

```
packet = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)
```

then you put the packet into a new PDF:

```
can.drawString(100, 100, "Kopačka")
    can.save()    
    packet.seek(0)  
    new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
```

and after that I merged the the empty PDF template and the new PDF with the critical text.

The problem is that the special diacritic chars are showing as black boxes like this: ⬛

I tried adding UTF-8 encoding to the definition function:

```
def __init__(self, e='utf-8')
```

and in the drawString function like this:

```
can.drawString(100, 100, "Kopačka".encode('utf-8'))
```

but it's still not showing correctly.

Is there a way to show those special characters in some other way?

Comment: Does the font that you are using actually contain those characters?

Comment: @usr2564301 it uses Arial font size 11 as default, I think it contains them but how can I change the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the solution:

I added the comment as @Aleksey said: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

And I changed the font from Arial to Calibri as @usr2564301 suggested like this:

First, imported modules:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
```

Then I downloaded Calibri Regualr.ttf in the folder and registered it in the app:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Calibri', 'Calibri Regular.ttf'))
```

And then changed the font in the canvas:

```
can.setFont("Calibri", 11)
```

Other than that, I left the UTF-8 encoding in the definition function and the drawString function.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Scripts that use UTF-8 encoding should start with this comment:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also you can setup usage of utf-8 this way:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

In your script unicode strings can be defined with 'u' prefix

```
can.drawString(100, 100, u"Kopačka")
```

Comment: thanks for this but it's not helping, I added the comment and the prefix but it's still showing the black box, while the sys throws errors :/